# Combining 2 rows into one

Tags: sql-server

I would like to combine 2 rows of a query results into one row where the output of one column from the second row would be populated into a column in the first one.

```
select INCDNT_TXT
    , INCDNT_TXT 
    , INCDNT_ID
    , SUBMIT_By
    , cast (SUBMIT_Date as date)
FROM
INCDNT_DATA join INCDNT
on INCDNT.INCDNT_ID = INCDNT_DATA.INCDNT_ID
where INCDNT_DATA.INCDNT_ID
 = 'Test' and (INCDNT_TXT_Detail = 'Account Name' or INCDNT_TXT_Detail = 'country')
```

the output is:

```
INCDNT_TXT INCDNT_TXT   INCDNT_ID   SUBMIT_By   SUBMIT_Date
Company1   Company1     Test         Peter       08/29/2017
France     France       Test         Peter       08/29/2017
```

I would like an output like:

```
INCDNT_TXT INCDNT_TXT2  INCDNT_ID   SUBMIT_By   SUBMIT_Date
Company1   France       Test         Peter       08/29/2017
```

thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you are certain that you will only ever have two records for each `INCDNT_ID`, `SUBMIT_By`, and `SUBMIT_Date` group, then you can try aggregating by these three columns:

```
SELECT
    MIN(INCDNT_TXT) AS INCDNT_TXT,
    MAX(INCDNT_TXT) AS INCDNT_TXT2,
    INCDNT_ID
    SUBMIT_By
    CASt(SUBMIT_Date AS date)
FROM INCDNT_DATA
INNER JOIN INCDNT
    ON INCDNT.INCDNT_ID = INCDNT_DATA.INCDNT_ID
WHERE
    INCDNT_DATA.INCDNT_ID = 'Test' AND
    (INCDNT_TXT_Detail = 'Account Name' OR INCDNT_TXT_Detail = 'country')
GROUP BY
    INCDNT_ID, SUBMIT_By, CAST(SUBMIT_Date AS date)
```

Comment: I just realized what you meant. there will be more records. basically in the table INCDNT_DATA.INCDNT_ID there are plenty of records and I would need to get always the Account Name and Country associated to the incident

Comment: @PeterM. There may be a simple fix to what I wrote above.  Can you edit your question and show us real data for the company and country?  Is there some logic by which we can identify a matching string?